# Cannot get LaTeX Workshop in VSCode to use MikTex

Tags: miktex, vscode, latex-workshop

I'm trying to set up LaTeX on VSCode with LaTeX Workshop and MikTex.

I downloaded MikTex and use the GUI to directly compile a demo.tex into PDF and it worked fine. But when I used LaTeX Workshop on VSCode I get this:

```
Latexmk: Missing input file 'fullpage.sty' (or dependence on it) from following:
  '! LaTeX Error: File `fullpage.sty' not found.'
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'hw1.log' for details
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
Latexmk: Examining 'hw1.log'
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
```

LaTeX Workshop can't seem to use the installation of MikTex I have.

I use RStudio so based on this [issue](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/2304) I suspect it might be using TinyTex, but I cannot confirm.

How do I tell LaTeX Workshop to use the MikTex I downloaded?

I use a mac.

Comment: `fullpage.sty` is part of the MiKTeX package [`preprint`](https://miktex.org/packages/preprint/files). Can you check if your MiKTeX has `preprint` installed? Though it should be installed on-the-fly.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Yes I do have that installed. That is why I think LaTeX Workshop is not using MikTeX but the TinyTex I have with RStudio. Any ways I can tell LaTeX Workshop to use MikTeX? Thanks!

Comment: Check the `PATH` environment variable?